# Extract Array From Index of a Array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to get the value of index 'image' from my output array
Here is my output of an array 
I am get index of fname from this array by using this code

```
<?php echo $this_>session->userdata('fname');?>
```

How I Get the index of Image from array userinfo. I want get also in session

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its multi dimensional array. Simply use below code.

```
$fname      =   $this->session->userdata('fname');
$imgIndex   =   $fname['user_info']['image'];
```